# There is no entry in Add/Remove Programs after installing my application (I used Setup project)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, setup-project, setup-deployment

I'm very new to Setup project in Visual Studio, I've just tried creating a one, it deployed my files as I configured in the setup project. But after testing the install file (.msi), there was something I can't understand:

1. There is no entry in the Add/Remove programs list in Control Panel but I tried re-running the setup and it showed a dialog saying that I couldn't setup because there was another version which has already been installed in the target computer, I should uninstall that version first, but I couldn't find an entry in Add/Remove programs and there is also no uninstall.exe file. I tried searching for all entries which contains my application executable file name in Registry and deleted these entries but It still shows me that dialog. (There must be some way through which it can detect another version installed on the target machine).
2. How I create an uninstall.exe for my deployed application in Setup project??? I thought it should be created automatically for me when I build my Setup project.

Your help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The target computer uses Windows XP SP3, in Add or Remove Programs window, I can see only a checkbox 'Show updates' (not 'View installed updates') and checking that checkbox doesn't show my installed application. As I said, I searched for my installed application info in Registry and deleted all the found results. I'm sure there hasn't been information anywhere in Registry. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no uninstall.exe when you are using msi packages to install applications. If you double click the msi of an already installed application you get the choice to do a repair or an uninstall.

What name did you give to your installation package? Maybe you left the default name or gave it some "weird" name different from your application and that's why you can't find it. In 7 you can sort the installed programs by install date and check what's been installed last, don't remember if it's possible in XP.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know all you talk about msi package. I simply named the msi file Setup.msi, Yes there is an entry named Setup in the Add/Remove programs list, I didn't think it's my application. Please tell me how to change the entry name without changing my msi name (I just want to name it Setup.msi) but the entry name should be my application name. Thanks. Please remember that I'm using Setup project in Visual Studio. Thank you.

Comment: If you go in the Solution Explorer tab of Visual Studio and you do a right click -> properties on your setup project you can choose the name of your msi file. With your setup project selected if you go in the Properties tab you can change the properties of your setup package (name appearing in the program list, version, ...).